# Complicated variable extraction / preg_match / replace / shortcodes for theme

Tags: php, html, regex, shortcode

Yes, i know i am reinventing the wheel but i do not want to use a framework or templating system.

**The idea:**

- Create a theme.php which holds the variables for a page layout ie.
  `$layout['default']`,`$layout['twocolumn']` etc
- Read theme.php `$layouts`
- Extract the layouts based on some variables ie. The page your viewing
- `preg_match` shortcodes within the $layouts ie. `{MODULEAREA=1}`
- Return the number of {MODULE= ie. =1 to use in `$module`
- Replace the shortcodes with content from the database
- Return `$layout['default']` with all html surrounding it and shortcodes replaced
- I would also need to grab the layouts for the admin section so i can
  set the modules in the correct place according to the theme

**Note:** Header and footer will be separate files "included" in the index.php

**Heres what i have so far:**

It sometimes replaces the shortcodes but removes all html, ideally i would like to replace the shortcodes and return the html with the new content.

```
$layout = '
<div class="module_area_one">
{MODULEAREA=1}
</div>
<div class="module_area_two">
{MODULEAREA=2}
</div>
<div class="module_area_three">
{MODULEAREA=3}
</div>
 ';

foreach(parselayout($layout, TRUE) as $module) {
    $row = $dmodule->getModuleByModuleArea($module);
    echo '
    <div class="module_wrap">
            <div class="module_title">'.$row[0]['module_title'].'</div>
            <div class="module_body">'.$row[0]['module_body'].'</div>
        </div>
    ';
}

function parselayout($layout, $check = FALSE) {
$tmp = explode("\n", $layout); 
    $str = array();

    for ($c = 0, $cnt = count($tmp); $c < $cnt; $c++) {
        if (preg_match("/[\{|\}]/", $tmp[$c])) {
            if ($check) {
                if (strstr($tmp[$c], "{MODULE=")) {
                    $matches = array();
                    preg_match_all("/\{MODULE=([\d]{1,3})(:[\w\d]*)?\}/", $tmp[$c], $matches);
                    if(!$matches){
                        return;
                    }

                    foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
                        $ret[] = $match;
                    }
                }
            } 
        } 
        else {
            if (!$check) {
                echo $tmp[$c];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($check) {
        return $str;
    }
}


public function getModuleByModuleArea($moduleMenuArea) {             
    $query = "SELECT module_title, module_name, module_body FROM wcx_modules WHERE module_menu_area=:module_menu_area AND module_active=1";
    $stmt = $this->queryIt($query);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':module_menu_area', $moduleMenuArea);
return $this->resultset();          
}
```

**Update:**

OK, so I'm a bit closer, the following code returns the modules in their respective place but it only shows one module which it repeats for all 3 menus, can you see anything wrong here.

I still have to figure out how to add a $layout['default'] = ''; as well.

**The preg_match_all:**

```
$pattern = '/\{MENU=([\d]{1,3})(:[\w\d]*)?\}/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches); 

//print_r($matches[1]);

foreach($matches[1] as $menu) {
    $row = $dmodule->getModuleByModuleArea($menu);
    $module = '
    <div class="module_wrap">
            <div class="module_title">'.$row[0]['module_title'].'</div>
            <div class="module_body">'.$row[0]['module_body'].'</div>
        </div>
    ';
}
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $module, $text);

echo $text;
```

**The string:**

```
$text = "
<div id='wrapper'>

<div id='maincontainer'>

<div id='leftcolumn'>
{MENU=1}
</div>


<div id='contentcolumn'>
{MENU=3}
</div>


<div id='rightcolumn'>
{MENU=2}
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div id='footer'> 
<div id='footer_disclaim'>

</div>
</div>
";
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using PHP's require or include.

Comment: I needed a way to read the MENU areas into the admin section for module placement dependent on the theme your using, this should work out just fine, if i can get it to work..

Comment: My problem is the way the modules are created and passed to the preg_replace, it will return one module for all 3 shortcodes, instead of modules 1,2,3.

Comment: Good luck getting help with your Rube Goldberg machine.

Comment: Ok, so how would you get the menu areas available in a theme in your admin section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $menu) {
    $row = $dmodule->getModuleByModuleArea($menu);
    $module = 'Simplified for readability';
}
// Now $module holds the last value calculated in the
// foreach-loop, and you are replacing all matches
// with that value.
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $module, $text);
```

You should take a look at [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
// This function will be called for every match of your
// regex and the return-value will be used as the replacement
$replaceCallback = function($matches) use ($dmodule) {
    $menu = $matches[1];
    $row = $dmodule->getModuleByModuleArea($menu);
    $module = 'Simplified for readability';
    return $module;
};
$text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replaceCallback, $text);
```